# Silverlight 3 or 4 multiple file upload and resize control

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

Where can I find a silverlight 3 or 4 user control that contains multiple file upload and resize capability?

**UPDATE:**
This will be used for uploading images.  We'd like to resize the images prior to posting up to the server.

Comment: This seems an article of what you want to accomplice: http://programmerpayback.com/2010/01/21/use-silverlight-to-resize-images-and-increase-compression-before-uploading/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with resize capability, but there is a nice multi file upload control at CodePlex.

**Features:**

- Select multiple files to upload
- Upload multiple files at the same time (asynchonous)
- Cancel a single upload, or clear the full list
- Shows the overall progress
- Error notification when upload failed
- Drag and drop files to the control

http://slfileupload.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

For a simpler solution that provides flexibility and extensibility check out this CodePlex project http://simpleuploader.codeplex.com/.

**Differences from other upload mechanisms:**

- Designed for developers.
- Simple! Easy to set up, use, extend, and customize.
- The code is not cluttered with unnecessary UI.
- Two core files that do the job.
- Designed to be used with BusyIndicator or similar custom status updaters.